# Core Data: SQLite not being updated immediately

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

There are two Entities- Document and Page. Document has a one-to-many relationship with Page.

I save the managed object context when I add document. At this point, there are no pages in them. While debugging I found that the writer context's save method does get called and is executed without error. I close and reopen the app and I can't find the previously saved Document objects. But, if I add a page in one of the document, then, the Document object appear in the table. I use a tool to view the SQLite file but my observation is not based on what I see in the tool. Even when I debug and see the number of documents present, I get 0 back when there is no page in them.

I am guessing that the Persistent Store Coordinator is doing some kind of optimization to write in batch. Can I force it to write and update the persistent store immediately? Is there a option that I can add while calling `addPersistentStoreWithType` on the persistent store object?

Note: Just FYI, I use [this](https://medium.com/soundwave-stories/core-data-cffe22efe716) pattern to organize the Managed Object Context(s)

**Fixed the issue. Here is the update**
So, I was saving the whole stack all the way up to the writer context. The bug was very silly. I was trying to save the main context on the main thread like this:

```
- (void)saveMainContext {
[self.mainManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{
    // Ensure that the main object context is being saved on the main queue
    __block NSError *error = nil;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.mainManagedObjectContext save:&error];
    });
    if(!error)
    {
        //Write to disk after saving on the main UI context
        [self saveWriterContext];
    } 

}];
}
```

As you can see, after trying to save the main context, I save the writer context. But, the bug was that I wasn't waiting for the main context to finish saving. After fixing the bug, my code looks like this:

```
- (void)saveMainContext {
[self.mainManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{
    // Ensure that the main object context is being saved on the main queue
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        [self.mainManagedObjectContext save:&error];
        if(!error)
        {
            //Write to disk after saving on the main UI context
            [self saveWriterContext];
        } 
    });
}];
}
```

And, this fixed the issue! Very silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you making sure you are saving your entire stack?  If you make a change in a private context you need to save that private context.  If you make a change in the main context (from the UI) then you need to save that context.  Only after all of your other contexts report `NO` to `-hasChanges` should you save the writer context (aka the master context in his design).

I suspect that is your issue.

### Response to OP

> Hmm. Did not know that. Thanks! So, are you suggesting that I may be well off if I do not check for "error" at all, and just check for the save's return?

What I am saying is that your save should look like this (note I also correct your unnecessary dispatch_async):

```
- (void)saveMainContext {
    [self.mainManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        // Ensure that the main object context is being saved on the main queue
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![[self mainManagedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
            NSLog("Failed to save context: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
            exit(1);
        }
        [self saveWriterContext];
    }];
}
```

The `dispatch_async` will be ignored because you are already on the right queue.

The call to `-save:` returns a `bool`.  If and **ONLY** if that returns `NO` do you react to the `error`.

Comment: Thanks Marcus! I went through the whole stack and made sure I was saving the contexts in order, like you suggested, and found the bug. Thanks so much! And yes, I should add hasChanges to my save methods.

Comment: And don't check the error after a save.  The author you were following is incorrect.  Check the return from `-save:` and respond to THAT.  The error can be populated even when no error occurs.

Comment: Hmm. Did not know that. Thanks! So, are you suggesting that I may be well off if I do not check for "error" at all, and just check for the save's return?

Comment: Updated answer to clarify my comments about `error`.